# How to run Z3 using multiple cores in Java?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, z3, solver, smt

I am trying to improve the time of my Z3 code.
Java is used in Z3 of my environment, and the version of Z3 is 4.8.10.

To enable parallel mode in C ++, you should set set_param ("parallel.enable", true) ;.
In the case of Java, how can I set it to parallel mode?
I would like to ask for sample code if you like.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The corresponding call in the Java bindings is called `setParameter`. See here:
https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/classcom_1_1microsoft_1_1z3_1_1_global.html#a38c6a465971f85a3c1826cf985ef3a56

Comment: Thank you!
In other words, should I use Global.setParameter("parallel.enable", "true"); to set to parallel mode?

Comment: That'd be a good way to start. I've never tried this myself, so there might be other gotchas, of course. Please report if you find issues with it.

Comment: Hi! I tried the method Global.setParameter("parallel.enable", "true"); 
But, the following warning has occurred.

WARNING: invalid parameter, unknown module 'parallel'

The parameters do not seem to be correct.

Comment: I just tried with Z3 version 4.8.11, and it works fine. Parallel-solving capabilities are rather new, you might have to upgrade your version of z3.